# How to use Google Endpoints from Chrome Extension

Tags: google-app-engine, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, google-cloud-endpoints

I try to connect to my localhost served Google Endpoints API from Chrome Extension. I managed to OAuth to Google Contact API other way than throught their JS Client but using `https://apis.google.com/js/client.js?onload=loadF` never call callback function. When I tried to call it manually, I get error in console: 
`Refused to execute inline event handler because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive` . It seems that background worker has not enough permission to load API but there is no info about it from console.

**My JS Code**

```
var apiRoot='//localhost:8080/_ah/api';

var loadF = function() {
  console.log("api init");
  gapi.client.load('my_api', 'v1', function(){
    console.log("callback");
}, apiRoot);
}
```

**My Manifest:**

```
{
  "name": "Linkeer",
  "version": "1.0",
  "description": "Linkeer ",
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "icons": {
    "128": "icon128.png"
  },
  "browser_action": {
    "default_title": "OAuth 2.0",
    "default_icon": "icon128.png",
    "default_popup": "options.html"
  },
  "options_page": "options.html",
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "matches": ["http://www.google.com/robots.txt*"],
      "js": ["oauth2/oauth2_inject.js"],
      "run_at": "document_start"
    }
  ],
  "permissions": [
    "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token",
    "http://localhost:8080/_ah/api"
  ],
  "web_accessible_resources" : [
    "oauth2/oauth2.html"
  ],
  "content_security_policy": "script-src 'self' http://localhost https://apis.google.com https://www.googleapis.com; object-src 'self'"

}
```

Comment: If you zip up the minimalist amount of code that replicates this I'll take a closer look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Today, I don't believe it's possible. There are at least two issues:

- Security policies for script inclusion are a significant blocker.
- For applications that use OAuth, the callbacks in the OAuth flow have never seemed to work properly. The popup appears, but never passes credentials back to the extension.

Answer (score 2):

For authentication I would suggest to use the [Chrome Identity API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/app_identity.html) which allows a much cleaner and easier implementation than the OAuth2 for Extensions library you are using at the moment.

I haven't found a good way to get the JS client library working inside of a Chrome extension yet (haven't tried in a while though). There's an [open feature request](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-javascript-client/issues/detail?id=64) for that though.

Directly creating the API requests as `XMLHttpRequest` should be easy enough though without using the library.

Comment: I can confirm this approach works. I took Identity API sample and slightly adjusted it pointing to my Endpoints URL and it works well.

Answer (score 1):

You will probably have to update your CSP with `'unsafe-inline'` which does reduce security but is probably required by the Google JS.

`"script-src 'self' http://localhost https://apis.google.com https://www.googleapis.com 'unsafe-inline'; object-src 'self'"`

Comment: Unfortunately,'inline event' is not allowed. Tried 'unsafe-eval', still didn't worked.